# How do I make this checkpoint system work in unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to have the player start from a start position at first. Then start from a checkpoint after they've completed level one. I've tried different iterations of this script, it is supposed to use a bool check if the player has passed through a trigger, and if they have their position will be equal to the checkpoint at Start. It has to remember the bool when the game is turned off and on again.

Right now the player always starts from the checkpoint.

I tried making my own boolean with playprefs but ended up using BoolPrefs, which still didn't work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody player;
    public Transform startPoint;
    public Transform checkPoint;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefsX.GetBool("level01Complete", false))
        {
            player.transform.position = startPoint.position;
        }

        if (PlayerPrefsX.GetBool("level01Complete", true))
        {
            player.transform.position = checkPoint.position;
        }
    }



    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "HubTrigger")
        {
            PlayerPrefsX.SetBool("level01Complete", true);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefsX.SetBool("level01Complete", false);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the BoolPrefs script I'm using currently.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPrefsX 
{


        public static void SetBool(string name, bool booleanValue)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(name, booleanValue ? 1 : 0);
        }

        public static bool GetBool(string name)
        {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(name) == 1 ? true : false;
        }

        public static bool GetBool(string name, bool defaultValue)
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(name))
            {
                return GetBool(name);
            }

            return defaultValue;
        }

}
```

I am new to using PlayerPrefs so there may just be something obvious that I'm overlooking.

HubTrigger is the trigger you pass through after completing level one. So it should be that the first time you play you start from one spot, then once you pass through hubtrigger, you've completed level one and from then on you start from the checkpoint when you load the game.

Comment: What's BoolPrefs?

Comment: In general you should **not** really use `PlayerPrefs` for storing user progress **at all** .. it is ment for non-sensitive preferences like music volume and data might get lost/changed easily

Answer (score 0):

`PlayerPrefsX` looks fine. It just seems like you're using it incorrectly. You should check `if (PlayerPrefsX.GetBool("level01Complete", false))`, and if that's true, then set the checkpoint position, and set the start position otherwise:

```
private void Start()
{
    if (PlayerPrefsX.GetBool("level01Complete", false))
    {
        player.transform.position = checkPoint.position;
    }
    else 
    {
        player.transform.position = startPoint.position;
    }
}
```

For `OnTriggerEnter`, you really only should set `level01Complete` there in the event you beat level 1:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "HubTrigger")
    {
        PlayerPrefsX.SetBool("level01Complete", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: HubTrigger is the trigger you pass through after completing level one. So it should be that the first time you play you start from one spot, then once you pass through hubtrigger, you've completed level one and from then on you start from the checkpoint when you load the game.                                                                 
                                                                                                                            
Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @games247 I edited my answer to address that. I also edited the question to include that information. This should answer your question now.